# I want show NO DATA AVAILABLE with backside grid lines in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I don't have data with me so i'm showing NO DATA AVAILABLE and i want backside with grid lines is this possible to showing

```
   Highcharts.chart('container', {

chart: {
    type: 'bubble',
    plotBorderWidth: 0,
    zoomType: 'xy'
},

title: {
    text: 'Highcharts bubbles with radial gradient fill'
},

xAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 1
},

yAxis: {
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false
},

series: [ ]

});
```

[jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/Kondaldurgam/t1ok4wze/)

Comment: You can look at the `showEmpty` property, but that won't show grid lines, only the axis lines and titles.  If you want axis lines, there needs to be data.  Alternatively, you could set a background image that shows the grid lines when you have no data.

Comment: I am wondering about setting initial min and max values for xAxis and yAxis. That may help you showing gridLines on your chart without data: 
https://jsfiddle.net/t1ok4wze/2/

Comment: I got exactly what you had done. but now i want to show NO DATA AVAILABLE in front of grid lines

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Kondaldurgam/18focztr/

Comment: Set zIndex for the text as it is done in Grzegorz Blachliński example

Comment: I'm used that zIndex also but its not working.Can show Example of above link

Comment: what happened @morganfree

Comment: You set zIndex via element.attr() - https://jsfiddle.net/18focztr/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function(chart) { // on complete

chart.renderer.text('No Data Available', 200, 195)
  .attr({
    zIndex: 99
  })
  .css({
    color: '#4572A7',
    fontSize: '16px'
  })
  .add();

});
```